Booting from live disk stuck on "EFI stub: Loaded initrd from LLINUX_EFI_INITRD_MEDIA_GUID device path"
I want to experiment with Ubuntu on a Lenovo laptop which has Manjaro installed (and nothing else, no Windows). I downloaded Ubuntu-24.04-desktop-amd64.iso on a Windows machine and burned it to a USB stick. After a lot of trouble I got the boot process to start on the Lenovo and fixed the black screen by typing e at the Try Ubuntu without installing option and replacing quiet splash with nomodeset, then F10 to boot. But now I am stuck with this message on the screen:
EFI stub: Loaded initrd from LLINUX_EFI_INITRD_MEDIA_GUID device path
What next please?
EDIT 24 May 2024 - I never did solve the problem. I changed to a different machine and have stopped trying to use the Manjaro machine for Linux. I have wiped it, installed Windows, and will keep it for things that won't run on Linux.

I gave up and re-installed Windows. I will now sell or give away this laptop. I am building Ubuntu successfully on a new device.

I had same issue, then i enabled Secure Boot on Bios. And reboot and booted without any problem
Edit
Another thing to consider is your pc has two same ram stick like 4gb+4gb
I had 4+8 and i tried with 8+8 then it booted without any problem now
I hope it helps

Thanks for the response. I have always found I have to disable, not enable, secure boot for any Linux installation.

Hello! Today i got this problem again, and secure boot is not helping anymore

But installing two same ram helped

It's me again, finally i deleted Linux and Installed windows, and now it's working like a charm
